# dynamic multi colored text in same label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Label in my .net page which I am trying am dynamically adding text to.  What I would like to do is add part of the text in green, and part in red.

The control in the page is set to forecolor=green.

I'm adding text through a stringbuilder, e.g

```
bodyText.Append("</br>");
bodyText.Append( startDate.ToShortDateString() + " - " + endDate.ToShortDateString());
```

Now I wish to append some more text, although in red rather than green.

Is it possible to do the the same Label?  Or does it need to be a separate Label side by side?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but something like this should work.

```
<span class="blue">First</span>
<span class="red">Word</span>
```

CSS

```
.blue
{
    display: inline;
    color: blue;
}

.red
{
    display: inline;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding markup when you add the texts meant to be red? Something like

```
bodyText.Append("<span style='color:red'>" + startDate.ToShortDateString() + " - " + endDate.ToShortDateString() + "</span>");
```